# Indenting multiple paragraphs in description

Tags: lists, indentation, paragraphs, enumitem, description

I am trying to put multiple paragraphs in a description, where the body text is indented by one `\parindent`, and I want to indent the second paragraph by one `\parindent` relative to the body text indentation.

Example of desired result

```
MY ITEM: Here is some text, and it is a paragraph. When it breaks
    to the next line, it is indented.
        This is my second paragraph. Notice how it has a leading indent, which
    is one \parindent relative to the rest of the description text, and a total
    of 2\parindent from the left margin.
```

This is my current result:

```
MY ITEM: Here is some text, and it is a paragraph. When it breaks
    to the next line, it is indented.
    This is my second paragraph. This result, however, does not indent
    my second paragraph relative to the body text in the \item.
```

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
\begin{description}[leftmargin=\parindent,topsep=0pt,partopsep=3pt,parsep=0pt,itemsep=3pt]
\item[MY ITEM] Here is some text, and it is a paragraph. When it breaks
    to the next line, it is indented.
    This is my second paragraph. This result, however, does not indent
    my second paragraph relative to the body text in the \item.
\end{description}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `listparindent=\parindent` to the environment's optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=\parindent,topsep=0pt,partopsep=3pt,parsep=0pt,itemsep=3pt,
    listparindent=\parindent]
\item[MY ITEM] Here is some text, and it is a paragraph. When it breaks
    to the next line, it is indented.

    This is my second paragraph. This result, however, does not indent
    my second paragraph relative to the body text in the \verb|\item|.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I could have sworn that I tried that, but I guess not. It works great!